# Ruby: How can I return all rows where an array column contains a given string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm working with some municipality data, and it's complicated by the fact that some municipalities are technically within multiple counties—which I handled in the database as an array, like so:

```
[<Municipality id: 11590, name: "Wisconsin Dells", county: ["Adams", "Columbia", "Juneau", "Sauk"], latitude: nil, longitude: nil, created_at: "2012-06-06 20:05:20", updated_at: "2012-06-06 20:05:20", municipality_type: "City">]
```

How can I construct a call **in Ruby** which would return all Municipalities where `county` contains a given string?

Ideally, this is how I'll list all cities in a given county, for example.

EDIT: I have `serialize :county` in my `Municipality` class.

Comment: You asked how to do it in Ruby, but do you mean in Rails? or do you want a pure Ruby solution?

Comment: I guess I preferred pure Ruby... but a Rails method would be fine.  I just don't want to be messing with SQL.

Comment: @jsonmklug -- but after re-reading... this is a Rails ActiveModel class, right? And you want to be able to call `Municipality.for_county("Columbia")` and have it return all Municipality that match, right?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott You're right—that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Muni < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_county(county)
    where %Q[county like '%"#{county}"%']
  end
end
```

Or, slower, but if you "just don't want to be messing with SQL":

```
def self.for_county(county)
  all.select { |m| m.county.include? county }
end
```

Comment: why do you need second `select`? And `where("county like ?", '%"#{county}"%')`

Comment: In case you're looking for the county "foo" and there's another county called "foobar" -- the SQL will match it, but the ruby `select` will filter it out.

Comment: you could search with quotes, couldn't you?

Comment: Also `LIKE` query won't use indexes in this case, what will cause performance issues

Comment: When I say "don't want to mess with SQL", I mean I'd like it to be database-agnostic.  If that's going to raise new problems, I guess I have to weigh the costs/benefits.

Comment: I'd suggest you escape the `county` parameter in your first approach.  Something like:  `where %Q[county like '%"' || #{connection.quote(county)} || '"%']`.  (Actual RDBMS string concat syntax may vary...)

Comment: @jasonmklug, don't know if the above works across dbs, but you may want to check out [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) if that's a concern.

Comment: The second option, `all.select { |m| m.county.include? county }` is working for me, and the performance hit is not an issue in my case (small db).  Can't speak for larger databases, though.

Thanks!